# Обособить присоединительные конструкции?

Tags: запятые, присоединительная-конструкция

**Страх, но небольшой(,) есть**.

**Наименьшим, притом отрицательным(,) зарядом обладает электрон**.

Нужны ли запятые? Мне кажется, что здесь присоединительная конструкция, которую нужно обособить.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. *Наименьшим, **притом отрицательным**, зарядом обладает электрон.*

Это присоединительная конструкция, о чем говорится в правилах **[Розенталя (пункт 1)](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120#pp120):**

Присоединительные члены предложения, которые содержат дополнительные разъяснения или замечания, вводимые в середину либо в конец высказывания, выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми.

***ПРИТОМ***, союз. (присоединяет предл. или чл. предл.). Вместе с тем, к тому же, кроме того.

2. *Страх, **но небольшой**, есть.*

Здесь значение также присоединительное, но грамматику можно объяснить по-другому. Сочинительный союз НО имеет в данном случае **противительно-уступительное** значение, его можно заменить союзом ***ХОТЯ И***. Тогда получаем: *Страх, хотя и небольшой, есть.*

Определительный оборот обособляется в позиции **после существительного.**

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ! А если так: _Наименьшим зарядом, притом отрицательным(,) обладает электрон_? Или: _Небольшой, но страх(,) есть_? Здесь определительный оборот стоит пперед определяемым словом. Хотя мне всë равно кажется, что нужно обособить.

Comment: (1) Наименьшим зарядом, притом отрицательным, обладает электрон. Обособление определительного оборота в постпозиции. А вот предложение (2) представляется мне некорректным, сложно объяснить такую грамматику.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, помогли.